# What is the maximum number of nodes that I can have including replicas in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have an index having 5 shards and 1 replica. What is the maximum number of nodes that I can have in elasticsearch cluster?

will it be 5 or 10? Also, can you please point to the documentation of the same.

Comment: could you please clarify your question? do interested in maximum number of data nodes? also, what's behind your question? you want to plan capacity? resources?

Answer (score 1):

With your case, you have 10 shards on your index (5 primary/5 replicas) and you can have a minimum of 1 shard per node, so your max number of nodes (if you have only one index) is 10.

**EDIT:** The right link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/overallocation.html

HtH,

Comment: i think you're wrong. first of all, he mentioned only 1 replica, second - it's obvious that you could have a node which doesn't have data - e.g. master node.

Comment: Of course, I just talking about data node ( so you can have any number of master node you want ) , but what do you mean about "he mentioned only 1 replica" ?  1 replica, is just one copy of 5 shards so 10 shards right ?

Comment: have no idea, to be honest, i guess question is very fuzzy :)

Comment: You're right, I don't get the aim of this question... Sharding is a huge point of ElasticSearch configuration and optimization... So question and answer are not relevante at all !

Answer (score 0):

You can separate out "master only" node, recommended option is to use 3 for high availability.

Then you can have  "Data only" node, that will keep each shard on separate node.

Also you could add client nodes, if you doing lot of aggregations and for security purpose.